# How to detect line break in pure JS

Tags: javascript

I have some code like this that implements the typewriter effect. The author has implemented it in such a way that at each space it pauses and a vertical cursor appears. In my case, this option is not suitable, I want to make this pause not on every space, but on every line break. I tried to use `\n` instead of `'  '` in the condition, but nothing works. Can you help?

```js
let textBox = document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1'),
    text    = textBox.innerText,
    newHTML = '';

for(i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    newHTML += '<span>'+text[i]+'</span>';
}
textBox.innerHTML = newHTML;

let spans   = textBox.querySelectorAll('span'),
    count   = 0,
    timeout = 0;

function typing_text(){
    spans[count].classList.add('visible');
    if(spans[count].innerText == '\n' || spans[count].innerHTML == '\n'){
        timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000));
        spans[count].classList.add('cursor');
    }else{
        timeout = 150;
    }

    if (count < text.length - 1){
        setTimeout(function() {
            spans[count].classList.remove('cursor');
            count ++;
            typing_text();
        }, timeout);
    }
}

typing_text();
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 290px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
/* Animation */
.index-title-main h1 span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.index-title-main h1 span.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
.index-title-main h1 span.cursor {
    background: #34DEB4;
    width: 2px;
    animation: blinking 0.5s step-start infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-title-main"><h1>Text 1 <br>Text 2, <br>Text 3</h1></div>
```

```js
let textBox = document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1'),
    text    = textBox.innerText,
    newHTML = '';

for(i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    newHTML += '<span>'+text[i]+'</span>';
}
textBox.innerHTML = newHTML;

let spans   = textBox.querySelectorAll('span'),
    count   = 0,
    timeout = 0;

function typing_text(){
    spans[count].classList.add('visible');
    if(spans[count].innerText == ' ' || spans[count].innerHTML == '  '){
        timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000));
        spans[count].classList.add('cursor');
    }else{
        timeout = 150;
    }

    if (count < text.length - 1){
        setTimeout(function() {
            spans[count].classList.remove('cursor');
            count ++;
            typing_text();
        }, timeout);
    }
}

typing_text();
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 290px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
/* Animation */
.index-title-main h1 span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.index-title-main h1 span.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
.index-title-main h1 span.cursor {
    background: #34DEB4;
    width: 2px;
    animation: blinking 0.5s step-start infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-title-main"><h1>Text 1 <br>Text 2, <br>Text 3</h1></div>
```

Comment: Can you do it at https://codesandbox.io/ ? It could be that \n are replaced by <br/> (just an assumption though)

Comment: Could you show us what `text` contains?

Comment: @NikitaChayka it all depends on the content of `text`. If it is pure text, then this won't show correctly in HTML. Otherwise the `<br/>` tag will be subdivided into 4 spans ('<', 'b', 'r', '>')

Comment: @lax48 realized it and already removed my comment :)

Comment: I've added a snippet. The cursor does not appear, I suppose the condition is being handled incorrectly?

Comment: replace `Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000))` with 4000 in order to see better the effect

Comment: Are you on a windows machine? It could be that you have `\r\n` as newline

Comment: @lax48, I changed the line break to a space, as the author had (second snippet). Look, now the vertical cursor appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to set the the random `timeout` when you encounter a `\n` character actually works. What is apparently not working is setting the `cursor` class. You were actually trying to apply it to the newline itself, and not to the space after the sentence. `\n` was, after all, the identified character with `spans[count]`.

I have updated your js, modifying it to `spans[count-1]`.

I have also added an iteration which makes sure to removing the `cursor` class from every letter, with no possibilities of making the cursor appear in unwanted situations.

```js
let textBox = document.querySelector('.index-title-main h1'),
    text    = textBox.innerText,
    newHTML = '';

for(i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
    newHTML += '<span>'+text[i]+'</span>';
}
textBox.innerHTML = newHTML;

let spans   = textBox.querySelectorAll('span'),
    count   = 0,
    timeout = 0;

function typing_text(){
    spans[count].classList.add('visible');
    if(spans[count].innerText == '\n' || spans[count].innerHTML == '\n'){
        timeout = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(1000));
        spans[count-1].classList.add('cursor');
    
    }else{
        timeout = 150;
    }

    if (count < text.length - 1){
        setTimeout(function() {

            //IE compatibleArray prototype method to iterate through NodeList:
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(spans, function (e) {
                e.classList.remove('cursor'); 
             }); 

            //Otherwise plain loop:
            //for (var e = 0; e < spans.length; e++)
            //    spans[e].classList.remove('cursor'); 

            count ++;
            typing_text();
        }, timeout);
    }
}

typing_text();
```

```css
body{
 background-color: #000;
}
.index-title-main{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 290px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
/* Animation */
.index-title-main h1 span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.index-title-main h1 span.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
.index-title-main h1 span.cursor {
    background: #34DEB4;
    width: 2px;
    animation: blinking 0.5s step-start infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-title-main"><h1>Text 1 <br>Text 2, <br>Text 3</h1></div>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks you! Just one nuance. IE doesn't support forEach, are there any alternatives?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to JS. IE still throws an error on this line.
`SCRIPT1004: Assumes ';'`.

Comment: My apologies, I told you the `for-of` loop is IE compatible. It is not the case. Answer code updated to implement a plain `for` loop, like: `for (var e = 0; e < spans.length; e++) spans[e].classList.remove('cursor');`

Comment: On top of this, you can use `Array.prototype.forEach` as you can now see in the question. `.forEach()` is actually supported in IE, but for Arrays and not NodeLists. According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#example) you can use `Array.prototype.forEach` to account for that and have it working in IE